# Using Websocket data coming from Redux state causes infinite component code rerender in Next js

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, next.js, jsx

I receive Binance Websocket data from my Redux state. But using this data in one of my components causes infinite code rerender in it. `const socketData = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.socket.data);` When I use this line in the component and log something in JSX return this way: `return <>{console.log("hello")}</>;` I receive infinite 'hello' in console, but right when I comment the websocket state line, it doesnt happen anymore. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Seems like something in your component leads to a change in `state.socket.data` every time the component renders, triggering yet another render. Could that be the case?

Comment: Actually I call my websocket action, which its payload is the websocket message data, in my index.tsx file (in its initial useEffect) and then get the data as `state.socket.data` in one of my components which I use it in index.tsx file. I know websocket works in a way to send new data frequently, but I dont really know why my whole component which uses the websocket data, should rerender and cause slow operation